# Joining two Core Data Results into 1 NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Currently I've a Tableview that need to display Channels and Conversations In the same tableview. The issue is that currently I need to make a Core Data Query in order to grab the data from this two different models. But the tableView only can handle 1 single Array/MutableArray I've tried to do.

```
var data: [AnyObject] = [["Math", "English II", "Programming"], ["Eddwin Paz", "Miguel", "Ryan", "Sponge Bob"]]
```

This currently works but I need to append more data.. instead of just a string. I need is the following.

```
{"type":"channel","#math"}, {"type":"conversation", "Eddwin"}
```

I've done this..

```
let channelDict = ["type":"channel", "value": currentPerson.nameUser, "id": currentPerson.idUser]
data.append(channelDict)
```

But When I try to display it on my tableView I get error..

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].valueForKey("value") as? String

    return cell

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Saying that table views can only handle one array is incorrect. Table views don't care about what data they display or where their data comes from. Having one array makes the implementation in ```tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath``` cleaner, but you can have as many arrays as you want and reference different arrays for different index paths.

Comment: Also, multiple dimensions is often the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of the `data` array after you add the channelDict:

```
var data: [AnyObject] = [["Math", "English II", "Programming"], ["Eddwin Paz", "Miguel", "Ryan", "Sponge Bob"], ["type":"channel", "value": currentPerson.nameUser, "id": currentPerson.idUser]]
```

That array contains two arrays and a dictionary, in that order. In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, when `indexPath.section` is 2, an exception will be thrown because you are trying to access the `indexPath.row` element of a dictionary.

```
data[2][indexPath.row] // Throws exception because dictionary cannot be subscripted
```